# UUID/GUID field and shards

Tags: postgresql, sharding, uuid

I am planning on using UUID field for storing items which can have a parent item. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I imagine there will be 3-4 levels at most. The design is to hold a structure such as `Corporations->sub-companies->stores/shops` So perhaps +/- 2 levels.

Now if I have the item and parent on same table wouldnt it be a problem in future if I want to divide data into multiple databases? What would be the best way to proceed?

```
                 uuid                 |             parent_uuid              
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 89b4052a-fd9a-43d3-b5f7-c69ee6ea9f5b |                                      
 c569ae30-87af-6bcf-fdd1-8143e3bae27a | 89b4052a-fd9a-43d3-b5f7-c69ee6ea9f5b 
 d7460788-ff07-e82d-83ed-5a0182ae2fbf | 89b4052a-fd9a-43d3-b5f7-c69ee6ea9f5b
```

Comment: how many nodes are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to proceed. If the hierarchy has an unknown amount of levels, you can't serialize it into fixed relations. But partitioning it is probably a bad idea. Perhaps you want a Graph Database?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to take a look at the [ltree extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) which lets you store hierarchical structures as materialized paths and supports queries against portions of the path. It would be the canonical solution for the problem you described.

I wouldn't worry about partitioning until you know you need it; at which time you will have a much better idea of the constraints that will govern which partitioning strategies you're going to use. I will note that partitioning on a uuid is a bad idea since the whole point of uuids is that they are randomly distributed in a very large key space and have no natural ordering.

Comment: Yes, I decided to worry about partitioning etc. later. Ltree looks interesting, but I am using doctrine and I wonder how it integrates with that. I have a lot of reading to do :)